# Does NUMA need to be explicitly enabled before calling kernel API functions?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, performance, numa

I'm converting a C++ application (running on Ubuntu) from single-socket to multi-socket. I would like to change the memory allocation to be NUMA-aware.

I know the application will need to call C API functions for memory allocation and core scheduling, but do I need to enable any Linux kernel settings before this for NUMA to work?

For example, do I need to change the grub boot command line etc?

Comment: [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) some relevant code. For example, is there some micro-benchmark which does not perform on NUMA the way you would expect? How do those timing figures compare to single-core measurements?